# Get all model variable values from database to view ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to print out all of my model values into my view.

I don't wish to "hard-code" it for each value, but rather have it dynamically grow accordingly to my models structure. This is so that non-developers can test out if everything gets inserted correctly into the database, what values are added etc

Currently I have this code in my controller that prints out all the variables in my model, but I'm not sure how to connect some certain objects values onto it

```
var result = "";
var myAssembly = typeof(Person).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
var properties = Converters.GetTypesInNamespace(myAssembly, "Domain.Models")
                           .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == "Person")
                           .GetProperties().ToList();

for (var i = 0; i < properties.Count; i++)
{
     result += properties[i].Name + Environment.NewLine;
}

return Ok(result);
```

And this is the custom method I use

```
public static Type[] GetTypesInNamespace(Assembly assembly, string nameSpace)
{
    return assembly.GetTypes()
                   .Where(t => String.Equals(t.Namespace, nameSpace, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                   .ToArray();
}
```

I'd like to get back a view that displays all the values for a Person with a certain id, ie Person/5 returns it's FirstName and LastName, but if I now add a new variable to my model - the view will display that as well

Comment: As stated in the tag [tag:model-view-controller] don't use that tag for [tag:asp.net-mvc].

Comment: Why not just use a `Dictionary<string, string>` as property on your ViewModel and loop through it in the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have model named Person and has some properties:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Add a controller action to accept person id :

```
 public IActionResult PestsonDetails(int id)
 {

        //you can search database with person id 
        Person p = new Person();
        p.FirstName = "FirstName";
        p.LastName= "LastName";
        p.Age = 28;

        Dictionary<string, string> personDetails = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in p.GetType().GetProperties())
        {

            var propName = prop.Name;
            var propValue = prop.GetValue(p, null);
            personDetails.Add(propName.ToString(),propValue.ToString());

        }
        ViewBag.personDetails = personDetails;
        return View();
  }
```

Then you could get the property name and value in view like :

```
@foreach (var personProperty in ViewBag.personDetails)
{
    @personProperty.Key
    @personProperty.Value    
}
```